# graphviz embed svg image

Tags: cairo, diagram

I am trying to generate a diagram with embedded SVG images.
If I run Graphviz with the regular `svg` command, the images are only referenced:

```
dot -Tsvg diagram.dot -O
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207182840/http://www.graphviz.org:80/content/help-embedding-svg-files) it says to build with `-Tsvg:cairo` but I get the following:

```
$ dot -Tsvg:cairo diagram.dot -O
Warning: No loadimage plugin for "svg:cairo"
```

I have `libcairo` installed, so I don't know what I am missing.